# Diferencia entre "autopista" y "carretera"

Tags: definiciones, significado

¿Hay alguna diferencia entre ***autopista*** y ***carretera***?

Ajá, sé que mi duda no está muy relacionada con el español, sino con las diferencias de características entre los dos objectos.

He buscado el diccionario RAE y también las imágenes en Google (cualquier imagen confunde). Me parece que son parecidos y no veo la diferencia.

Answer (score 9):

[**Carretera**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7gxxR8n) es el término general para los caminos por los que transitan (o pueden transitar) vehículos:

> 1. f. Camino público, ancho y espacioso, pavimentado y dispuesto para el tránsito de vehículos.

[image: Imagen de carretera]

[**Autopista**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4U9ht5a) es un tipo específico de carretera:

> 1. f. Carretera con calzadas separadas para los dos sentidos de la circulación, cada una de ellas con dos o más carriles, sin cruces a nivel.

[image: Imagen de una autopista]

Comment: ¡Gracias por tu respuesta, Leonardo, y bienvenido al sitio! Tu respuesta es clara y concisa, y te animo a que nos des más respuestas como esta. Solo un apunte: en este caso tu respuesta quedaría mejor si añadieras alguna imagen representativa de ambos conceptos, para que la diferencia entre ambos quede absolutamente patente. ¿Te animas?

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo. Por favor envíe algunas fotos distintas si no te molesto. Ya que en “google imágenes”,  toda confunde. Y qué significa “¿Te animas? ” :)

Comment: @Fabiola para saber eso tendrás que hacer otra pregunta. ¿Te animas a hacerla? :-)

Comment: @Charlie ¿por qué no hacelo rapido? ;) si eso significa “dare you? / do you feel like? / do you want to?”

Comment: @Fabiola porque no me siento con la confianza necesaria como para hacer una traducción rápida al inglés que incluya todas las sutilezas de la expresión. Si lo preguntas en el sitio obtendrás respuestas de más gente además de la que te pueda dar yo.

Comment: @Charlie vale. Eres muy considerado.

Comment: Esto es correcto +1. Añado que se puede hacer un paralelo con las palabras en inglés así. Carretera = road, Autopista = highway/freeway

Answer (score 3):

Una Carretera, no necesariamente es un camino público, ni tiene que ser ancho, ni tampoco tiene que ser espacioso ni necesariamente pavimentado.

Carretera es cualquier recorrido o trazado que conecte un lugar con otro por donde podrían circular

- vehículos mecánicos
- vehículos de tracción animal

Según el recubrimiento las hay

- pavimentadas:

  [image]
- destapadas (sin pavimento):

  [image]

Según el uso:

- Privadas (por ejemplo dentro de fincas, haciendas, o dentro de clubes
  privados) y cuya circulación está restringida.
- Públicas, ya sea contruídas por el gobierno o a través de concesiones para circulación de todos los ciudadanos.

En cuando al ancho hay carreteras que:

- Tienen 1 sola calzada con solo 1 carril, donde solo cabe 1 (uno) vehículo en 1 (uno) sola dirección (si viene un vehículo en dirección contraria, uno de los dos se ahorilla para permitir el paso del otro vehículo).
- Las hay de 1 calzada y 2 carriles donde caben 2 vehículos cada uno en dirección contraria.
- Las hay de 2 calzadas, una para cada dirección, con 2 o más carriles, tal que las calzadas pueden estar separadas una de la otra por

  - líneas pintadas en el piso
  - topes o algún elemento continuo o discontinuo que sobresalga del piso

[image]

```
- separador central de diferentes anchos
```

Etiquetar una carretera con el término "**AUTOPISTA**" depende de cada país y de su reglamentación.

Por ejemplo en Colombia usamos el término "**AUTOPISTA**" para referirnos a ciertas carreteras pavimentadas que conectan a las ciudades capitales de departamento, pero no necesariamente implica que tengan calzadas separadas ni que no existan pasos a nivel.

Por ejemplo existe la "Autopista Bogotá-Medellín", unos 412 km.
En su comienzo por allá en los años 1970's era una carretera pavimentada de solo 1 calzada con 2 carriles uno para cada dirección, con cruces a nivel.
Hace unos 20 años empezaron las obras de ampliación a doble calzada y ahora cuando sale de Bogotá es de 2 calzadas con separador central (de apróximadamente 2 metros), con 2 carriles cada calzada con algunos pasos a nivel, y es así unos 280 km hasta aproximadamente Puerto Triunfo, y luego vuelve a ser de solo de 1 calzada con 2 carriles uno para cada sentido y el separador central son las rayas pintadas en el piso y tiene cruces a nivel. La orografía andina hace muy difícil y costoso construir carreteras de más de una calzada.

[image]

Comment: @Leonardo es una interesante definición de una organización supranacional; sería adecuado que los foristas nos dieran ejemplos de carreteras que en su respectivo país denominen "autopistas", aunque ya el asunto se sale del contexto de lo meramente lingüistico.

Comment: Creo que vale notar que las autopistas son especializadas para vehículos de motor y frecuentemente penalizan usos no autorizados, como tracción animal. Esta respuesta ya hace la aclaración de que las carreteras pueden permitir tracción animal.