# ¿Tienen un nombre aparte las carreteras privadas?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, solicitud-de-término, definiciones, adjetivos

En la última pregunta de Fabiola, *[Diferencia entre "autopista" y "carretera"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/27218/12637)*, hemos leído la definición que da el DLE para *carretera*:

> **[carretera](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7gxxR8n)**
>
> ```
> De carreta.
> ```
>
> 1. f. Camino público, ancho y espacioso, pavimentado y dispuesto para el tránsito de vehículos.

Me ha llamado la atención lo de *camino público*. Según las definiciones de *[público](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UYbbTs8)* como adjetivo, puede ser:

> 1. adj. Conocido o sabido por todos.
> 2. adj. Dicho de una cosa: Que se hace a la vista de todos.
> 3. adj. Perteneciente o relativo al Estado o a otra Administración. *Colegio, hospital público.*
> 4. adj. Dicho de una cosa: Accesible a todos.
> 5. adj. Dicho de una cosa: Destinada al público.

Esto me lleva a la siguiente duda: ¿existen las carreteras privadas? Quiero decir, podríamos tener una carretera en una finca privada (ancha, espaciosa, pavimentada y dispuesta para el tránsito de vehículos), que no pertenezca al Estado y no sea accesible a todos y por tanto no esté destinada al público en general. ¿Se denominaría *carretera* o tendría una denominación diferente? ¿Sobra el adjetivo *público* en la definición, o se debe interpretar de alguna otra forma a las mencionadas?

Comment: Yo creo que sería un "**camino** privado", según el ejemplo que pones para la finca (como opuesto a un [camino vecinal](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6xxQ4ub). Si de verdad fuese una "carretera" (que la definición del DRAE dice que es "ancho y espacioso" pero no dice cuánto ni cómo de largo) posiblemente sería una - prohibitivamente cara - carretera privada. Supongo que tenemos autopistas "privadas" (o privatizadas) porque privatizar una carretera (q es + peq.) no sería rentable (así como hacer una _carretera_ en lugar de un _camino_ hacia tu finca)

Comment: **Camino privado** o **vía privada** las llamaría yo. _Carretera_ siempre la he entendido, primero como pública y segundo como de longitud considerable (10 o más kilómetros diría yo)

Comment: Interesante pregunta! Dado el hecho que la palabra *público* tiene antónimo y la palabra *carretera* no tiene, debo pensar que el adjetivo de "público" no es realmente necesario para definir lo que es una carretera. Los otros adjetivos si son significativos (pavimentado, ancho, etc.) ya que modifican la definición (i.e. camino es una via no pavimentada).

Answer (score 1):

Las "*carreteras privadas*" son llamadas autopistas privadas o si se refieren a una vía por la que hay que pagar peaje, autopistas de cuota. Normalmente al pensar en una carretera la primera idea que viene a la mente es su anchura, no el tipo de uso.

Comment: Agregaría que no es solo la anchura o capacidad de la vía, si no su diseño que permite velocidades más altas a los vehículos que la utilizan, pero no sé si es una acepción local del término (escribo desde Chile).

Answer (score 0):

Hablar de "Carretera" es una forma coloquial para referirnos a un tipo general de senda por la que de forma habitual transitan vehículos. Sin embargo, para evitar equivocaciones dentro de ese lenguaje lato, habría que interpretarlo también en el contexto jurídico, que es donde los conceptos realmente se clarifican, pues muchos cuando hablan de "Carretera" lo hacen para referirse a un simple camino o incluso a una carretera como una pista de autovía, autopista... dependiendo del marco del círculo de quien se expresa. Así pues, lo idóneo no es hablar de "Carreteras" sino de "Vías" y sus distintos tipos, donde la "Carretera", es simplemente un tipo de vía con sus propias características que la diferencian de un camino, una Autovía o una Autopista, (Anexo I de la ley de Seguridad Vial RDL 6/2015).

El art. 1 del Reglamento General de Circulación nos dice que *las leyes de tráfico se aplican en todo el territorio nacional, afectando a los titulares y usuarios de las vías y terrenos de carácter público y a los privados de uso por una colectividad indeterminada de usuarios*.

Bajo este prisma, en España no hay "Carreteras Privadas", pero si existen "Vías Privadas" tanto de uso público (concesión), como de uso privado, y que pueden poseer los elementos habituales que conforman las "Vías", como son la "Calzada" y los "Carriles".

El uso de las "Vías Privadas" es exclusivo de los propietarios y de aquellos que tengan una autorización por parte de estos. Los propietarios serán los que establezcan las normas. "Tendrán ese carácter aquellas que tengan conexión con terrenos privados y tengan titularidad privada. " Ejem. Caminos que conectan dos casas dentro de un mismo terreno privado. Si la utilización de la "Vía Privada" es también de uso público, las normas del titular o titulares, estarán adecuadas de forma general a las de tráfico. Por ejemplo las calles de una urbanización.

---

- ¿*Existen las carreteras privadas*?. En España no. Existen las "Vías Privadas". Coloquialmente se denominan Caminos Privados, Pistas Privadas, Carriles Privados, Sendas Privadas...
- ¿*Se denominaría carretera o tendría una denominación diferente*?. Jurídicamente, la denominación acorde sería la de "Vía Privada de uso exclusivo" (dentro de una finca privada, en una zona privada que va a un residencial de uso exclusivo...). Coloquialmente si esta pavimentada puede llamarse "carretera", "pista"... dependiendo de la zona geográfica y el contexto.
- ¿*Sobra el adjetivo público en la definición, o se debe interpretar de alguna otra forma a las mencionadas*?. En España, jurídicamente no sobra el adjetivo público ya que "Carretera" se interpreta como una "Vía común", donde rigen las normas de tráfico y del Estado (ordenación del territorio, medioambientales...).

Coloquialmente, una "carretera" suele interpretarse como camino, aunque la característica principal de una "carretera" sea que ésta se encuentre pavimentada.

---

**Diccionario Panhispánico del Español Jurídico**.

*Carretera*

1. Adm. Vía de dominio y uso público proyectada y construida fundamentalmente para la circulación de vehículos automóviles.
2. Adm. A los efectos de la normativa de tráfico, vía pública pavimentada situada fuera de poblado salvo los tramos de travesía.

Answer (score 0):

No creo que *público* sea necesariamente un criterio de clasificación. Es simplemente una característica. Si un *rascacielos* es un "edificio alto", no tiene por qué existir una palabra específica para "edificio bajo". De igual forma, un camino ancho que no es público se llama simplemente *camino*.