# Significados de “¿Te animas?”

Tags: significado

Cuando dice **¿Te animas?**, ¿qué quiere decir? Debería hay varios usos / significados como “¿qué te parece?”, ¿sí? ¿Es un dicho coloquial?

Comment: [Enlace al comentario](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/27218/diferencia-entre-autopista-y-carretera#comment45667_27219) que dio lugar a la duda de Fabiola.

Comment: Como la traducción al inglés de este uso de _animarse_ no me quedaba clara, [la he preguntado](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/462074/280768) en [English.SE].

Comment: @Charlie *Animarse a hacer algo* lo tomo como el equivalente de *tener ganas de hacer algo* y, por tanto, la expresión más cercana vendría siendo *I feel like doing [sth]*.

Comment: @Ustanak pero "animarse" para mí implica que has tomado una decisión tras superar un pequeño escollo. "Me animé a redactar la pregunta" podría significar que en algún momento consideraste que redactarla era mucho trabajo pero en algún momento superaste ese escollo. Ese "me animé" me implica un "bueno, venga, vamos a ello" que no sé si existe en el "I feel like doing something", que lo veo más como "me apetece hacer algo".

Comment: @Charlie El asunto es complicado. Aquí en Chile, no lo usamos necesariamente con esa connotación, sino con la que había mencionado. Creo que depende de la región que uno se encuentre.

Comment: @Ustanak pues entonces eso hace la pregunta aún más interesante. Anímate a redactar tu propia respuesta. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Si te fijas en la definición de *animarse* (usos pronominales de *[animar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2hSyy7m)*), nos encontramos lo siguiente:

> 9. prnl. Cobrar ánimo y esfuerzo.
> 10. prnl. Decidirse, determinarse a hacer o decir algo. *Se animó A venir.*

En el caso que nos ocupa estamos ante la acepción 10. Cuando alguien pregunta *¿Te animas?* se refiere a animarse a hacer algo previamente mencionado o que se sobreentiende, como en:

> ¿Te animas [a plantear la pregunta en el sitio]?

También se usa con otros tiempos, como en el ejemplo del dicionario:

> Se animó a venir.

El diccionario lo define como "decidirse" o "determinarse a hacer algo". Sin embargo, echo en falta una pequeña sutileza, un punto de subjetividad. Para mí las expresiones "se animó a venir" y "se decidió a venir" no son completamente equivalentes. Me explico.

La segunda, "se decidió a venir", es más neutra, y puede implicar que la persona tenía dudas sobre si venir o hacer otra cosa, y al final se decidió por venir. Aunque también se puede interpretar como que la persona estaba entre venir o no hacer nada, y que lo único que le impedía venir era que tenía que superar un pequeño escollo: superar el tedio que le produce la acción, por ejemplo. Esto es primordial para el uso de "animarse": implica que la persona tiene que superar un obstáculo (que puede ser leve); pero además implica otra capa de subjetividad, y es que según el hablante la acción determinada supondrá algo positivo para quien la realiza. Véase el siguiente ejemplo:

> ¿Cómo que no quieres venir al cine? ¡Venga, anímate!

Este ejemplo indica que la persona solo tiene que superar su indecisión o su aburrimiento para pasar un buen rato, para hacer algo que le va a sentar bien. Nótese como aquí no se puede cambiar "anímate" por "decídete", que implicaría otra cosa:

> ¿Vas a venir al cine o no? ¡Venga, decídete!

En el caso del comentario que dio origen a la pregunta:

> Tu respuesta quedaría mejor si añadieras alguna imagen [...]. ¿Te animas?

El uso de "animarse" ahí implica que a) el usuario tendrá que hacer un esfuerzo para cumplir con lo que se le animó a hacer, y b) entiendo que al hacerlo recibirá un beneficio: su respuesta quedará más completa, la gente le votará más, etc.